# error when I use exports but working with module.exports

Tags: node.js

If I use `module.exports = mongoose.model('People', PersonSchema, 'People');` than below code is working fine

```
People = require("../models/people");
People.find(function (err, docs) {});
```

but with `exports = mongoose.model('People', PersonSchema, 'People');` get **ERROR** at `People.find()` saying `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'find'`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the value of `module.exports` is the value that's returned by `require()` within other modules. `exports` is just a reference copy of `module.exports` offered for convenience.

When you're only *modifying* (or "*augmenting*") the export object, either will work as they both refer to that same object. But, once you intend to *replace* the object, you must set the replacement to `module.export`.

From [Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) (emphasis mine):

> Note that **`exports`** is a reference to **`module.exports`** making it suitable for ***augmentation only***. If you are exporting a single item such as a constructor you will want to use **`module.exports`** directly instead.
>
> ```
> function MyConstructor (opts) {
>   //...
> }
>
> // BROKEN: Does not modify exports
> exports = MyConstructor;
>
> // exports the constructor properly
> module.exports = MyConstructor;
> ```